# Expand Amazon ebs volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have Ubuntu ec2 instance. I have attached EBS volume which is restored from snapshot.

Volume size is 100GB and there is partition of 30GB containing data and 70GB blank space. EBS volume has `x86 boot sector(ntfs)` file system. Now I want to expand this 30GB partition to 100GB. How can I expand this partition in Ubuntu instance?

Comment: [Click Here](http://www.surekhatech.com/blogs/-/blogs/expand-ntfs-volume-from-ec2-linux-instance) for step to step guide for above problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Extending a Linux File System](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html#recognize-expanded-volume-linux)
Or [Expanding a Linux Partition](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/storage_expand_partition.html) could help.

Update: How about [ntfsresize](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/ntfsresize.8.html)? I have not tried it, but seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: I have gone throw those links. it provide information about only ext2, ext3, ext4 and xfs filesystem. My volume has ntfs filesystem

Comment: I have solved it, First create extended partition using parted or gdisk. then use ntfsresize to resize partition, Thanks Andrei D.

Comment: [Here is a link](http://www.n2ws.com/how-to-guides/how-to-increase-the-size-of-an-aws-ebs-cloud-volume-attached-to-a-linux-machine.html) to a recent (~year ago) description of the process with AWS GUI screen shots.